# svn+ssh asks for password endlessly , why?

Tags: svn, ssh

Our svn+ssh repository asks for password like 8 times when browsing the repository with TortoiseSVN or merging or checking-out in cli. Nothing fancy about our configuration, quite ordinary `svnserve` on a `CentOS` machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the beauty of `ssh` is that you can set up keys to use instead of passwords in the first place.  `svn` may need to make more than one connection in some circumstances, and I thought it normally cached that password for at least the current run, but it doesn't look like it is.

Consider keys instead:

```
remoteHost# ssh-keygen
remoteHost# scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub serverHost:

serverHost# mkdir ~/.ssh
serverHost# chmod 700 ~/.ssh
serverHost# mv ~/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then it'll never ask for a password again!

Comment: so the reason is svn connects multiple times and does not consider the fact that this various connections relate to the same run ?

Comment: Well, that's the only thing I can think of.  But it doesn't make a huge amount of sense.  Clearly, though, either the password is being typed wrong or it's not caching the result and needs to make multiple connections.  Is there differing pause-lengths between the asking?  (ie, something that indicates activity going on).

Comment: in rare cases in the middle of an operation it asks for password

Comment: time to break out tcpdump :-)